# Solr SpellCheck/Suggester and Fuzzy Search in v4.8.1

Tags: solr

I want to use the Solr SpellCheckComponent/Suggester to get query word suggestions based on the query word and fuzzy search + wildcard search. For example, /suggest?q=spackove would return stackoverflow.

Right now I have the following elements in place, but only wildcard searching seems to work, even when changing the spellcheck accuracy attribute. No corrections are done on fuzzy matching, only incomplete correctly spelled entries are returned. 
spellcheck.build=true has been performed. Anything I'm missing?

config.xml :

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
   <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">suggest</str>
      <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.jaspell.JaspellLookupFactory</str>
      <str name="field">STREETNAME_DUTCH_EXACT</str>
   </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
  <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggest</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.count">30</str>
 </lst>
 <arr name="components">
  <str>suggest</str>
 </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Kind regards,

S. Cow

Answer (score 0):

You should use accuracy field in your search component. 
`<str name="accuracy">0.7</str>`

This is same as saying `fieldVelue~0.7`

By the way in your "stackoverflow" version you should use smaller value since your text is alot diffrent from the original one.